# Retrieving response after posting data using PHP Curl

Tags: php, post, curl, oauth-2.0, response

I am trying to make an API call to Localbitcoins API using Curl, but I am having difficulty getting the response to return properly. I have looked at my Curl request and nothing looks out of place.

Here is the API call I am trying to get:

**Base URL:** https://localbitcoins.com/oauth2/access_token/

**Required arguments:** `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password`, `grant_type=password`

**Optional arguments:** None

If successful, JSON like so will be returned immediately:

```
{
  "access_token": the access token,
  "scope": "read",
  "expires_in": seconds to expiry,
  "refresh_token": a refresh token
}
```

and here is the function I have written to try and retrieve the `access_token`:

```
function authenticate($parameters) {
    $url   = 'https://localbitcoins.com/oauth2/access_token/';
    $parameters['client_id'] = 'redacted';
    $parameters['client_secret'] = 'redacted';
    $data = http_build_query($parameters);

    // Initialize the PHP curl agent
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === false)
        throw new Exception ("curl Error: " . curl_error($ch));

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_status != 200)
        throw new Exception("Request Failed. http status: " . $http_status);

    curl_close($ch);

    // Trim any whitespace from the front and end of the string and decode it
    $result = json_decode(trim($result));
    if (($error = get_json_error()) !== false) {
        throw new Exception("json_decode failed: " . $error);
    }

    // Verify that we got a valid response
    if (!isset($result->status))
    {
        throw new Exception("API response did not contain 'status'");
        exit;
    }
    if ($result->status == 'error')
    {
        throw new Exception("API call failed: " . $result->message);
        exit;
    }

    // The API call succeeded, return the requested data
    return $result->data;
}
```

and calling the function:

```
authenticate(array(
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'redacted',
        'password' => 'redacted'));
```

All this returns is FATAL ERROR and a 400 ERROR for BAD REQUEST. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since API URL is on HTTPS you have to disable SSL peer verification by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's worth your time to develop for the current Localbitcoins API. It's very poorly documented with a lot of broken features. If you look at the Developer forum, it's not well maintained and its riddled with complaints:

https://localbitcoins.com/forums/#!/dev/developers-and-affiliates

I personally inquired on the status of the API with one of the Localbitcoin developers, and he told me that they are pushing out an updated API within the next two weeks.

As per your question specifically, it seems like the issue has existed since October 2013:

https://localbitcoins.com/forums/#!/dev/developers-and-affiliates#problems-with-grant-typepa

Doesn't look like anyone from the Localbitcoins team has resolved it either. I think you are better off holding off for their new API.

Cheers!

Comment: This seems to be the case... I'll try to troubleshoot this a little bit more but this seems like the likely answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this...

```
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo nl2br($result);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It's not coming up with anything. This is a console application, by the way. I used print_r($result) and just `1` returned.

Comment: TRY THIS...

$ch = curl_init($URL); ///THE URL YOU WANT TO SEND
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml')); //YOUR HEADER TYPE
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "[YOUR XML CONTENT]");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   echo nl2br($output);
   curl_close($ch);

Comment: once you got the response just parse the data and put to your variables...hope it works for you it works for me.

Comment: Will give a shot and report back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: set your file header in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER what is your 'Content-Type:

Comment: Getting this back now:

`{"error_description": "No 'grant_type' included in the request.", "error": "invalid_request"}`

Even though there is a grant_type defined... This might be an issue with the site I believe.

Comment: so something wrong with your "xml format" or "text" you are sending...it works..now just fixed the code you are sending.

i am sending "xml" format on that code. how about you?

see this..2 lines

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml')); //YOUR HEADER TYPE curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "[YOU PUT YOUR XML VARIABLE HERE]");

Comment: I'm sending the arguments as an url encoded array. I believe I should be using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, no?

Comment: you are right..i think it is working now...just check your arguments

in that case your curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

Comment: Still no luck, still giving me an invalid grant, but it oddly has an newline character in between each letter in the error message: `{"error_description": "* error\n  * i\n  * n\n  * v\n  * a\n  * l\n  * i\n  * d\n  * _\n  * g\n  * r\n  * a\n  * n\n  * t", "error": "invalid_grant"}`

Comment: try to remove this... echo nl2br($output); just get the output. I just use that in xml response.


in curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "[field=value1&field2=value............put your array here...]");

Comment: or this format curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)

Comment: enable the POST     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: can you change these value to "1"

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks! **EDIT**: Nothing working. I think the other answer I got may have the reason why!